# Passing edge weights to graphviz_layout in networkx

Tags: networking, layout, graph, graphviz, networkx

everybody cannot find how to pass name of property of list of weights to graphviz_layout in networkx. Something like this:

```
nx.spring_layout(G, weight='weight.sum')
```

but with `nx.graphviz_layout(G, ...)`. Maybe somebody will know?

Answer (score 6):

If I got you right, you want to specify which edge attribute to use as edge weight for the graphviz layout. From the [NetworkX docs](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html?#graphviz-layout) I don't see that this is possible.

However, the `weight` attribute is used by the layout algorithms in graphviz. This is what it says:

> [weight](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3aweight)
>
> Weight of edge. In dot, the heavier the weight, the shorter, straighter and more vertical the edge is. For other layouts, a larger weight encourages the layout to make the edge length closer to that specified by the [len](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3alen) attribute.

With this you can [set the edge weight](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#edge-attributes) for each edge in the network:

```python
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1, 2, {'weight': 4})
```

or

```python
g.add_edge(1, 2)
g.edge[1][2]['weight'] = 4
```

or

```python
g[1][2]['weight'] = 4
```

If you want to set a default weight for the edges, you can pass this as an [argument to the graphviz program](http://www.graphviz.org/content/command-line-invocation) that you want to use in `graphviz_layout`:

```python
nx.graphviz_layout(g, prog='dot', args='-Eweight=4')
```