# NetworkX and wxPython - How to add edge weight?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, wxpython, networkx

I try to figure out how to add a edge weight to my code example but i cant find any good documentation in combination with wxPython.

I want the edges, so to speak the distances of the nodes to be like in my list "edge_weight". Labels and everything else is working as expected.

As a small addition is it possible to add something like a shadow effect or anything similar to the master node to highlight it?

My code looks like this:

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas

class NetworkFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(1280, 768))
               
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
                
        G = nx.Graph()
        
        nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        node_sizes = [6500,4000,4000,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500]
        node_color = ["#00d992","#00d9c8","#00d9c8","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9"]
        edges = [(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,2),(7,2)]
        node_label = {0: "Printer",
                      1: "Case",
                      2: "Electronics",
                      3: "Plastic 1",
                      4: "Plastic 2",
                      5: "Plastic 3",
                      6: "Metal 1",
                      7: "Metal 2"} 

        edge_weights = [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]  # ?????             
        
        G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
        
        nx.draw(G, node_size = node_sizes, node_color = node_color, labels = node_label, with_labels=True)  
        
        plt.axis('off')
        
        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App()
  app.frame = NetworkFrame()
  app.frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the following assumptions based on the information provided in your question:

- You want to make sure that the egde lengths are based on the edge weights
- You want to highlight the master node

Now lets begin with the first one.

**1. Draw edge lengths based on edge weights**
You can use pygraphviz with networkx to get the layout of the graph in such a way that the edge lengths are according to your choice.

To do that, first you need to scale the edge weights, so that the distance between the nodes is visible in the graph (given that you have a min. value of `0.1` and max. value of `1`, the edges won't be visible). I have scaled them by 10, but you can use whatever scaling method suits you.

```
new_edge_weights = [ int(x*10) for x in edge_weights]
```

Next, create dictionary with keys as 'len'(this attribute will be used by pygraphviz, see [here](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:len)) and values as the edge lengths

```
lengths = {}
for e,l in zip(edges, new_edge_weights):
    lengths[e] = dict(len=l)
# {(1, 0): {'len': 10},
# (2, 0): {'len': 5},
# (3, 1): {'len': 5},
# (4, 1): {'len': 1},
# (5, 1): {'len': 1},
# (6, 2): {'len': 1},
# (7, 2): {'len': 1}}
```

Now use graphviz_layout to get the positions of the nodes and draw the graph

```
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos,
        node_size = node_sizes,
        node_color = node_color,
        edge_weights='len',
        labels = node_label,
        with_labels=True)
```

Here is how your graph will eventually look like:
[image]

**2. Highlight your master node (Assumption the master node is `node 0: Printer`**.
This can get a bit tricky. So one way to do this, is to draw another node of smaller size and different color on the master node itself.

```
# Set the nodel label to empty for the new node
node_label[len(node_label)+1] = "" 

# Set the size of the new node smaller than the master node
master_idx = 0
node_sizes.append(node_sizes[master_idx]-300)

# change the master node color to black
node_color[master_idx] = "#000000"
# set the color of the inner node (new smaller node)
node_color.append("#00d992")

# Set the position of the node same as the master node
pos[len(pos)+1] = pos[master_idx]

# Add node to the graph
G.add_node(len(node_label))

# Draw the graph
nx.draw_networkx(G,
    pos=pos,
    node_size = node_sizes,
    node_color = node_color,
    edge_weights='len',
    labels = node_label,
    with_labels=True)
```

[image].
**Note that I have scaled the node sizes to make the edges visibile. You can change it as per your requirement and adjust the egde length accordingly.**

```
Here is the full program
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout


class NetworkFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(1280, 768))
               
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
                
        G = nx.Graph()
        
        nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        node_sizes = [650,400,400,250,250,250,250,250]
        node_sizes = [x+1500 for x in node_sizes]
        node_color = ["#00d992","#00d9c8","#00d9c8","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9","#00b4d9"]
        edges = [(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,2),(7,2)]
        node_label = {0: "Printer",
                    1: "Case",
                    2: "Electronics",
                    3: "Plastic 1",
                    4: "Plastic 2",
                    5: "Plastic 3",
                    6: "Metal 1",
                    7: "Metal 2"}

        edge_weights = [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]  # ?????             

        new_edge_weights = [ int(x*10) for x in edge_weights]

        lengths = {}
        for e,l in zip(edges, new_edge_weights):
            lengths[e] = dict(len=l)
            
        G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
        nx.set_edge_attributes(G, lengths)
  
        pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')

        # Set the nodel label to empty for the new node
        node_label[len(node_label)+1] = "" 

        # Set the size of the new node smaller than the master node
        master_idx = 0
        node_sizes.append(node_sizes[master_idx]-300)

        # change the master node color to black
        node_color[master_idx] = "#000000"
        # set the color of the inner node (new smaller node)
        node_color.append("#00d992")

        # Set the position of the node same as the master node
        pos[len(pos)+1] = pos[master_idx]

        # Add node to the graph
        G.add_node(len(node_label))

        # Draw the graph
        nx.draw_networkx(G,
            pos=pos,
            node_size = node_sizes,
            node_color = node_color,
            edge_weights='len',
            labels = node_label,
            with_labels=True)

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App()
  app.frame = NetworkFrame()
  app.frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

**References**

- [graphviz_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout)
- [pygraphviz](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz)
- [Set edge lengths according to weights in graphviz_layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553462/8160718)

Answer (score 1):

use `add_weighted_edges_from` in place of `add_edges_from`

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas


class NetworkFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)
    self.SetSize(wx.Size(1280, 768))

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)

    G = nx.Graph()

    nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    node_sizes = [6500, 4000, 4000, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500]
    node_color = ["#00d992", "#00d9c8", "#00d9c8", "#00b4d9", "#00b4d9", "#00b4d9", "#00b4d9", "#00b4d9"]
    edges = [(1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 0.5), (3, 1, 0.1), (4, 1, 0.1), (5, 1, 0.1), (6, 2, 0.1), (7, 2, 0.1)]
    node_label = {0: "Printer",
                  1: "Case",
                  2: "Electronics",
                  3: "Plastic 1",
                  4: "Plastic 2",
                  5: "Plastic 3",
                  6: "Metal 1",
                  7: "Metal 2"}

    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

    nx.draw(G, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_color, labels=node_label, with_labels=True)

    plt.axis('off')

    self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
    self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    app.frame = NetworkFrame()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```